# How to add blob image to pdf file?

Tags: java, blob, pdfbox

I'm working with png images stored in the database as a blob , and I'm also using `PDFBox 2.0.13` to do this task .. 
I used this

```
LosslessFactory.createFromImage ( BufferedImage) // null pointer exception raised
```

I don't know if I should use :

```
PDImageXObject.createFromFile
```

as it works for png image type .. is there any way to use it and create file object from blob to use it with `PDImageXObject.createFromFile` ??

If there any other way that I could add blob png image to `pdf` file .. that would be a great help .

I'm using this method

```
public byte[] getArchiveDocument(String id, String index, String type) throws Exception {

    String idx = getIDForDocument(index, id, type);
    System.out.println(idx);
    String s="  ";

    String z="";


    SystemDbManager sx=new SystemDbManager();
    sx.executeStatment(s);

    Blob blob = null;
    ResultSet  rs=null;


    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();

    try {
        rs=sx.getResultSet(z);

        if (rs.next())  {



            blob=rs.getBlob("imageole");    

               InputStream in = blob.getBinaryStream();

               PDPage page = new PDPage();
               document.addPage(page);
               File f = File.createTempFile("stream2file", ".tiff");
               f.deleteOnExit();
                try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f)) {
                    IOUtils.copy(in, out);
                }

               PDImageXObject img = PDImageXObject.createFromFileByContent(f, document);
               PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
               contentStream.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
               contentStream.close();
               in.close();
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
    rs.close();
    sx.close();

    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    document.save(byteArrayOutputStream);
    document.close();
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

}
```

error stack

```
java.io.IOException: First image in tiff is not a single tile/strip
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.CCITTFactory.extractFromTiff(CCITTFactory.java:435)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.CCITTFactory.createFromRandomAccessImpl(CCITTFactory.java:203)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.CCITTFactory.createFromFile(CCITTFactory.java:164)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject.createFromFileByContent(PDImageXObject.java:257)
at ps.gov.gpc.tools.ArchiveModel.getArchiveDocument(ArchiveModel.java:117)
at ps.gov.gpc.siteService.action.ShowArchiveDocAction.execute(ShowArchiveDocAction.java:48)
at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:304)
at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

thank you .

Comment: put your blob in a temporary file, e.g. `File.createTempFile(...)`

Comment: if `LosslessFactory.createFromImage(PDDocument document, BufferedImage image)` throws an NPE then there's a null somewhere. Either `document` or `image`. Check these. If they are not null, please share the stack trace.

Comment: I'm using this code now @TilmanHausherr

Comment: Please check your class path. You are using a version older than 2.0.13. Because in the current version this IOException (your TIFF file is unusual) is caught, and a different strategy is attempted.

Comment: You will also need a plugin to read TIFF images, unless you have jdk 9 or higher e.g. twelvemonkeys.

Comment: can you recommend any plugin to use please  @TilmanHausherr

Comment: either jai_imageio.jar or the twelvemonkeys tiff plugin. https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray` as mentioned in [doc](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.13/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/image/PDImageXObject.html#createFromByteArray-org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument-byte:A-java.lang.String-)? Code below is working fine for me (JDK 8):

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PDFBox {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = "/home/yohanesgultom/Documents/example.pdf";
        PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        try {
            // convert image to byte array
            // for Blob use java.sql.Blob.getBytes(long pos, int length)
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/yohanesgultom/Pictures/php7.png"));
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputStream);
            byte[] imageByte = outputStream.toByteArray();

            // convert byte array to image object
            PDImageXObject imageObject = PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray(doc, imageByte, null);
            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
            // draw image on top of page
            contentStream.drawImage(imageObject, 25, 600);
            contentStream.close();
            doc.addPage(page);
            doc.save(path);
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

There is a nice example on converting `java.sql.Blob` to `byte[]` in [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-convert-BLOB-to-Byte-Array-in-java).

Comment: I cant find createFromByteArray in this version of pdfbox

Comment: You should double check your version, then. Also make sure there is no version conflict. If you are using `2.0.13` as you mentioned in the question, the method should be there as the doc suggests.

Comment: @YohanesGultom From the line number in the exception, I suspect he is using version 2.0.3 from 2016.

Comment: While your answer is right to use `createFromByteArray` for a blob, reading the file with ImageIO and saving it isn't needed. You could use `IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)` to create a byte array.